# How can i draw simple line in column chart in google-charts API?

Tags: html, web, google-visualization

I have a simple column chart. using the google-charts API:
[image]

**JS code**:

```
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo $str ?>);

    var options = {
    title: 'Business Optimization Per Predicted Conversion Rate',
    bar: {groupWidth: "70%"},
    colors: ['purple','grey'],
    fontSize:20,
    legend: { position: "none" },
    width: 900,
    backgroundColor: { fill: '#efeff0'},
    };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div_1'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

My question is: How can i draw simple line here?
Horizontly to the X-axis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535668/drawing-visual-lines-in-google-charts

Comment: @azalea I already try this. this is not working.